# How to import Moment-Timezone with Aurelia/Typescript

Tags: momentjs, aurelia

I've imported momentjs properly. It's working fine, but when I go to try to import moment-timezone, I can't get it to work. I don't have access to any functions.

Here's my aurelia.json file where I'm loading them from npm:

```
{
      "name": "moment",
      "path": "../node_modules/moment",
      "main": "moment",
      "exports": "moment"
},
{
      "name": "moment-timezone",
      "path": "../node_modules/moment-timezone",
      "main": "moment-timezone",
      "deps": [ "moment" ],
      "exports": "tz"
}
```

and here's where I'm trying to load them into the file:

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import * as moment from "moment";
import * as tz from "moment-timezone";

@autoinject
export class GlobalUtil {

}
```

Is this the right way to load them? It's not working for me unfortunately.

Now when I try to specify a timezone, I get a "Moment Timezone has no data for America/New_York." Then it console.logs(7am), which is not the correct time.

Comment: I think you have the deps backwards. Based on moment-timezone's pjson, I thinkyou should have moment as a dep of moment-timezone.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I just edited the question now. Good catch. We're closer, but still not there. In my node_modules file, I have a data/packed/latest.json file in the moment-timezone folder, but I don't know how to load those in..

Comment: Are you using JSPM or Webpack??

Comment: @CallumLinington Neither. I'm using Aurelia-CLI which uses npm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe I can help a bit with this. In order to give decent instructions, I'll add step-by-step instructions for the entire chain of adding moment/moment-timezone to an Aurelia CLI app.

**Install moment.js**

- `npm install --save moment`
- `typings install dt~moment --global --save`

**Install moment-timezone**

- `npm install --save moment-timezone`
- `typings install dt~moment-timezone --global --save`

> Note: I'm assuming you want to use TypeScript. If not, skip the second steps from the installation instructions above.

Next, configure both in the "dependencies" section of **aurelia.json**:

```
{
    "name": "moment",
    "path": "../node_modules/moment",
    "main": "moment"
},
{
    "name": "moment-timezone",
    "path": "../node_modules/moment-timezone",
    "main": "moment-timezone",
    "deps": ["moment"]
}
```

Finally, let's wrap this up with a simple example on how to actually use this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

export class App {
  message: string;

  constructor() {
    // basic example of using moment().tz
    this.message = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "Europe/Amsterdam").format();
  }

}
```

That should be it! So far so good, at least for the configuration part. But, as your question already indicates, you may receive an error in the trend of:

> Moment Timezone has no data for Europe/Amsterdam. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/

This means that, by default, moment-timezone has no knowledge of that specific timezone. As the link from the error message mentions, you have to add it yourself. For example like:

```
moment.tz.add([
    'America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0',
    'Europe/Amsterdam|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);
```

Add as much timezones as you'd like to this array. Or download/use a predefined bundle from the momentjs website (see link above).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Now, I have the predefined bundle of data in the NPM package that got downloaded. How do I import it with moment-timezone to avoid having to add all of them individually?

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm getting `TypeError: moment is not a function`

Comment: Changing import statement to `import moment from 'moment';` made it work.