# How to get all available time zones in Moment Timezone?

Tags: timezone, momentjs, aurelia, typescript-typings

I want to get a list of all available time zone names, I use `moment.tz.names` function for this purpose, as you see:

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment-timezone";

public availableTimeZones = moment.tz.names();
```

But I get null. I use TypeScript + Aurelia + Webstorm to develop the program, and I installed "moment-timezone" and "moment":

```
npm install --save moment
typings install dt~moment --global --save
npm install --save moment-timezone
typings install dt~moment-timezone --global --save
```

Actually, I have to add all available time zones by `moment.tz.add` .
I want to have all available time zone. I don't want to add some of the zones and then use them. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452470/how-to-import-moment-timezone-with-aurelia-typescript can help

Comment: I want to have all available time zone. I don't want to add some of zones and then use them.

Comment: you need to include **moment-timezone-with-data.js** in your project. See https://momentjs.com/timezone/. Click on the files to see their content. **moment-timezone.js** does not include the timezone list.

Comment: So perhaps should import the file with the list. E.g `import "moment-timezone-with-data";`

Comment: @Benny indeed, link in that post provides a downloadable collection of all timezones.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps. import "moment-timezone-with-data" was the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Moment-Timezone with Aurelia/Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452470/how-to-import-moment-timezone-with-aurelia-typescript)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of the question linked by @Benny; and the OP has stated that solution worked here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import "moment-timezone-with-data" is the solution.